# How to write a relay command on Checkox changed event in DataGridCheckboxColumn in WPF MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a data grid where It has a DataGridTemplateColumns, So my intention is to write a command to checkbox changed event in MVVM way, for that DataGridTemplateColumn doesn't give a suggestion like Command to start with the relay command. How can I achieve this. I want to disable a combo box in the page when checkbox is checked, and when it's unchecked I want to enable the combo box. What is the best approach for this using MVVM pattern? Are there any other ways we can write commands for this type of scenarios? 
As I'm new to WPF, Any suggestion or advice will be a great help. Thanks in advance!

```
<Window x:Class="CustomCtrldemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomCtrldemo"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomCtrldemo.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowVM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>


    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowVM }}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="TxtFilterGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=FilterText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Load Grid"  Width="100" Height="20" Command="{Binding LoadGridCommand}" />
        <Grid x:Name="gridAuthors" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" >
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgAuthors" ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Book Title" Binding="{Binding  Path=BookTitle}" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MVP Enabled" Binding="{Binding  Path=IsMVP}" **Command** />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Load Control"  Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Set Content"  Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtbox1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="20" />
        <TextBox Name="txtUniqueId" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <local:LoadControl />
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="center" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Button Content="OK"  Width="100" Height="20"/>

            <Button  Content="Cancel"  Width="100" Height="20"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the above code in DataGridCheckBoxColumn, Command word cannot be seen in suggestion. Can anyone give me a guidance how to achieve this task?

Comment: Please, share what have you tried so far

Comment: If you make IsMvp a propfull in your Author (row) viewmodel you can act in the setter rather than use a command.

Comment: Where is the `ComboBox` that you want to disable? Please improve your example.